# a question about cdf player embedable demonstration

Tags: programming

I have now my first application to be exportable as a cdf. If I safeguard as a cdf it works. But if I embed it in an html page It proposes to download the cdf player which is already on my computer. What must I do. I use FireFox

Comment: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/20057

Comment: Thanks It works in internet Explorer. I was not aware of it since I use exclusively Firefox and the duplicate is about Chrome

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, same issue. Browsers are ending their support for NPAPI plugins (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/npapi) due to security issues.

Comment: it has been 2 years since WRI said they will port the demonstrations to the cloud so one can run them without plugin. Any one knows anything about the current status of this work?